# Group ascending values in list

Tags: python, list, grouping

If I have the following list of values:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
```

How can I group these values to get the following:

```
b = [[1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4], [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4], [1,1,2,3,4,4,4]]
```

I tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
list1 = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] <= 4:
        list1.append(a[i])
```

Comment: You want to group every `9` values?

Comment: @MayankPorwal looks like increasing subsequence. Another homework 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to loop over each element and build the output list -

```
a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,2,3,4,4,4]

curr = a[0] 
temp = [] 
b = []

for num in a:
    if num < curr:
        b.append(temp)
        temp = []
    temp.append(num)
    curr = num
b.append(temp)
```

As you build the output list you need to check if the current element is smaller than the previous element and if it is you need to append your current sublist to the final list and start building a new sublist. You also need to remember to add the last sublist to your final list after you loop over all the elements in the initial list since that will not be added in the loop.

Comment: It works! That is very informative, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

```
b = []
sub_1 = []
for num, i in enumerate(a):
    sub_1.append(i)
    if num + 1 == len(a):
        b.append(sub_1)
    elif i == 4 and a[num + 1] != 4:
        b.append(sub_1)
        sub_1 = []
```

Comment: with the example input of `a` in the question this outputs an empty list since `i > 4` never occurs

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.